# Expressing the Golomb-Dickman constant in closed-form

Tags: integration, limits, closed-form, constants

Is there a way to express the [Golomb-Dickman constant](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Golomb-DickmanConstant.html) ($\lambda$) ([A084945](https://oeis.org/A084945)) in a [closed-form expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed-form_expression)? [Here's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golomb%E2%80%93Dickman_constant) the Wikipedia article for the Golomb-Dickman constant, but it's not as useful in my opinion.

It seems that all of the expressions for the constant either use a limit or an integral.

Comment: In which interpretation are you interested ? The probabilistic permutation  $M(\Pi_n) \sim \lambda n$ (formula [10](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Golomb-DickmanConstant.html)), or the number theoretic interpretation in term of $\sum_{n \le x} \frac{\log Lpf(n)}{\log n} \sim \lambda n$ ?

Comment: @reuns The OP is interested in a _closed-form expression_, probably just because there isn't one to be found at Wikipedia or Wolfram, meaning it's not likely there _is_ one. Such questions often get upvoted at SE, for reasons I'll never understand.

Comment: @ProfessorVector I am aware that there *likely* is not a closed-form expression - however, I am also aware of the fact that the users here are better at finding such things than I would ever be.